# Solve conditional probability equation with formulas

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I got a tricky math conditional probability task:
Find $$P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A})$$
Having
$$P(A) = a = 0.47$$
$$P(B) = b = 0.24$$
$$P(A \cap B) = c = 0.11$$

Solution: The thing is, that by definition the conditional probability of A
given B is:$$P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Thus, moving into the calculation, it's not hard to swap variables and:
$$P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A}) = \frac{P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$$

The thing is, that we already got an input in the task: $$P(A \cap B) = c = 0.11$$
However, $$P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0.47*0.24 = 0.1128$$And this number is not rounded, what means, that by calculating the result by using only `P(A) and P(B)` variables would be different than implementing $P(A \cap B) = c$ variable.

My complete solution: Using Bayes' theorem, we can find the following $P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A}) = \frac{P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})}{P(\overline{A})}$

$P(\overline{A}) = 1 - P(A) = 1 - 0.47 = 0.53$

Then  $P(A \cap B) = P(B \mid A) * P(A)$

Therefore: $P(B \mid A) = \frac {P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac {0.11}{0.47} = 0.234$

Now we need to find $P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})$ by using a rule: $P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$

Where $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 0.47 + 0.24 - 0.11 = 0.6$

Then: $P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A}) = 1 - P(A \cup B) = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4$

Finally: $P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A}) = \frac{0.4}{0.53} = 0.7547...$

Is my solution reasonable? The tricky thing is the dependency between the events A and B

Comment: Can you give a reference or citation for what you state is a rule: "$P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$" ??  Later in your write-up you say that $1 - P(A \cup B)$ actually equals $P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})$ instead of $P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A})$ as per your rule.  So, what _is_ the value of $1 - P(A \cup B)$? $P(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A})$ or $P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A})$? Or are you thinking the two are equal?

Comment: Your work is good, and in my opinion, exactly what the problem composer intended.  My only criticism of your posting is that there is a typo in the following excerpt of your posting: "... by using a rule: " $$P(\overline{B} \mid \overline{A}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$$  It should be $$p(\overline{B} \cap \overline{A} ) = 1 - p(A \cup B).$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate I could be mistaken.  However, judging by the overall analysis of the OP's (i.e. original poster's) work, I think that this is merely a typo.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote it wrongly, gonna correct that atm

Comment: While I was formatting code in math.stachexchange, something clearly went wrong, probably after copying-pastying I forgot to change it, my bad, sorry for the confusion
@DilipSarwate

Comment: OK. I recommend deleting the "calculation" of $P(A\cap B)$ as $P(A)*P(B)$ which is valid only when $A$ and $B$ are _given_ to be independent.  You don't _need_ to _calculate_ the value of $P(A\cap B)$; you are _told_ that $P(A\cap B) = 0.11$. If for personal reasons you insist on including $0.1128$ in your answer, write it as (say) "Note that $A$ and $B$ are dependent events since $P(A\cap B) = 0.11$ does not equal $P(A)*P(B) = 0.1128$" which will display your knowledge and understanding of probability concepts to your grader.

Comment: @DilipSarwate this is the exact thing I wanted to draw attention to (that's why I left it there to see the difference between the given input 0,11 and P(A) * P(B)). While having P(A AND B) given in the task instead of not using it and calculating P(A AND B) = P(A) * P(B) = 0,1128 w'd be a completely different result. That's why I want to show you my approach.